# Keep collection ordered

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array in my view model. Is it possible to make items be ordered all the time even after pushing additional items?

Example:

```
[ { a: 4 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 2 } ];
```

Are displayed on the UI ordered by property `a`. So `[ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 4 } ]`.
Then I load some new items from the server - `[ { a: 5 }, { a: 3 } ]`, push them into array and the array is still displayed ordered on the UI. Is it possible to do using core ko functional?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `.sort()` method each time data is pushed inside the array - you can't directly insert them in the middle of an array (see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#pop_push_shift_unshift_reverse_sort_splice)).

In your case, you can do the following:

```
// Todo: insert (push) all inside the observableArray when you retrieved it from the server

// Now sort the data
observableArray.sort(function (left, right) {
    return left.a == right.a ? 0 : (left.a < right.a ? -1 : 1);
});
```